# parallel mutable assignment in F#

Tags: f#

I want to swap both references, is there a nice way make such a construct work ?

```
 let mutable sarlast = ref (Array.copy ar)
 let mutable sarcurr = ref (Array.copy ar)
 ... some code ...

 sarcurr, sarlast <- sarlast, sarcurr
```

Comment: This example is a bit crazy: you have a mutable variable pointing to a `ref` of a reference type!

Comment: good point. Arrays are already reference type, so there is no need to  use ref another time. I guess that's a good illustration of 'referential transparency' if not of good code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `<-` is single assignment and tuple is immutable in F#.

You can define an infix function for the purpose (one-liner suggestion by @bytebuster):

```
let (>-<) x y = let temp = !x in x := !y; y := temp

// Usage
let a = ref [|1|]
let b = ref [|2|]
a >-< b
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `let (>-<) x y = let temp = !x in x := !y; y := temp`

Comment: the let temp = ref (!x) is not trivial, and quite illustrative

Comment: @bytebuster nice one... squeezing the langage juice until the last drop

Comment: If I had to do something like this then would just use a normal named function instead of the symbolic operator >-< i.e let swap x y = ...